# Find the Matrix of a Linear Transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

It's been a few weeks since the subject was covered in my Linear Algebra class, and unfortunately linear transformations are my weak spot, so could anyone explain the steps to solve this problem?

> Find the matrix $A$ of the linear transformation $T(f(t)) = 3f'(t)+7f(t)$ from $P_2$ to $P_2$ with respect to the standard basis for $P_2$, $\{1,t,t^2\}$.

The resulting answer should be a $3 \times 3$ matrix, but I'm unsure of where to start when it comes to solving this problem.

Comment: The first column of the matrix is the vector $T(1)$, the second column is the vector $T(t)$, and the third column is the vector $T(t^2)$. Try it out. All these vectors should be written with their coordinates in terms of the basis $\{1, t, t^2\}$, but luckily this is a easy basis to work with in $P_2$.

Comment: @HenryT.Horton as in evaluate the equation for each?

Comment: Yes. For example, $T(3 + 2t) = 3(3 + 2t)' + 7(3 + 2t) = 3 \cdot 2 + 21 + 14t = 27 + 14t + 0t^2$, so $T(3 + 2t)$ would correspond to the vector $$\begin{pmatrix} 27 \\ 14 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Ahh! So then I express my resulting answer after evaluation in terms of being a combination of the three parts of my basis? That makes perfect sense...Thanks alot @HenryT.Horton

Comment: Yes. In this case there isn't any extra work to be done, since the basis here is so easy to write things as a linear combination of. In general, you would have to solve a system of linear equations to find out what the components of the resulting vector with respect to the given basis is.

Comment: Aside: linear algebra is the study of linear transformations. If linear transformations are your weak spot, you should be seriously worried.

Comment: @ChrisEagle For the scope of my class, linear transformations are the only thing i struggle with, I'm unfortunately stuck with a teacher who's teaching style makes it very hard to learn in class. I've got a strong grasp of RREF and Eigenvalues, which pretty much runs the range of what we were able to cover in the semester. I understand the concept of linear transformations, i just have trouble grasping the method of solving some problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE** Given a finite dimensional vector space $\Bbb V$ and a basis $B=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ of $\Bbb V$, the coordinates of $v$ in base $B$ are the unique $n$ scalars $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ such that $v=\sum_{k=1}^n a_kv_k$, and we note this by writing $(v)_B=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$.

---

All you need is to find what $T$ maps the basis elements to. Why? Because any vector in $P_2$ can be written as a linear combination of $1$, $t$ and $t^2$, whence if you know what $T(1)$, $T(t)$ and $T(t^2)$ are, you will find what any $T(a_0 +a_1 t +a_2 t^2)=a_0T(1)+a_1 T(t)+a_2 T(t^2)$ is. So, let us call $B=\{1,t,t^2\}$. Then

$$T(1)=3\cdot 0 +7\cdot 1=7=(7,0,0)$$

$$T(t)=3\cdot 1 +7\cdot t=(3,7,0)$$

$$T(t^2)=6\cdot t +7\cdot t^2=(0,6,7)$$

(Here I'm abusing the notation a bit. Formally, we should enclose the two first terms of the equations with $(-)_B$ )

Now note that our transformation matrix simply takes a vector in coordinates of base $B$, and maps it to another vector in coordinates of base $B$. Thus, if $|T|_{B,B}$ is our matrix from base $B$ to base $B$, we must have

$$|T|_{B,B} (P)_B=(T(P))_B$$

where we wrote $P=P(t)$ to avoid too much parenthesis.

But let's observe that if $(P)_B=(a_0,a_1,a_2)$ then $a_0T(1)+a_1 T(t)+a_2 T(t^2)=a_0(7,0,0)+a_1 (3,7,0)+a_2(0,6,7)$ is the matrix product

$$\left(\begin{matrix}7&3&0\\0&7&6\\0&0&7\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}a_0 \\a_1 \\a_2 \end{matrix}\right)$$

And $|T|_{B,B}=\left(\begin{matrix}7&3&0\\0&7&6\\0&0&7\end{matrix}\right)$ is precisely the matrix we're after. It has the property that for each vector of $P_2$

$$|T|_{B, B}(P)_B=(T(P))_B$$

(well, actually

$$(|T|_{B,B} (P)_B^t)^t=(T(P))_B$$

but that looks just clumsy, doesn't it?)